# How to call REST service on Windows Phone 8.1 Physical Device

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8.1

I am calling REST service in Windows Phone 8.1, It is running in Simulator but not running on Device. I stuck here, how to deal with?
See my code below:

```
 System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:32002/XXXXX.svc/live_login?uname=abc&pwd=123");

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
 string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var dialog = new MessageDialog(data);
 await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localhost is not the same for your device and your PC.

When run on device your code is trying to connect to rest service on your phone which, obviously, isn't working.

Comment: Szymon, then what to do? If I replace localhost with my PC IP then, app is running but not running on different network. Please help brother. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, that depends on what is your network architecture and what you're trying to achieve. You can either host your REST service on some public hosting service on Internet, set up cloud service or even host the service from your machine. The latter will probably require use port forwarding if you want it to be visible form internet. Google it up :)

Comment: Szymon, thanks brother, after all I come to zero means same as silverlight!hoho